# CloudKit Record Type Inheritance

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, cloudkit, ckrecord

I am starting out on adding CloudKit to my iOS app.  I have a fully completed data model already that was implemented using Core Data.  I used inheritance for my `NSManagedObject` classes.  Is that something I can also do with a CloudKit schema?  For example, can I make an Employee RecordType inherit from a Person RecordType?

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {

  @NSManaged var uuid: NSUUID!
  @NSManaged var birthday: NSDate
  @NSManaged var name: String?
  @NSManaged var age: Int16
}

class Employee: Person {

  @NSManaged var salary: Int16
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Kit record types are more like database tables. There's no such concept as classes or inheritance. A record type simply has 1 or more fields.

If you wanted an Employee record type you would need to have fields for salary, uuid, birthday, name, and age in that one record type.